# VBScript ends before saving and closing Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a very basic VBScript that I want to be able to call from Task Scheduler to open an Excel document, refresh all and then save and close it. 
I've been playing various bits of code I've found online (as I'm very new to this) and I can get it to open and refresh all, but the VBScript closes before it will save and/or close the workbook.

I have tried adding 'WScript.Sleep' (with various amounts of time) as well as DoEvents to allow Excel to finish, but the script still closes before saving and closing workbook.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = 
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\llfs01\ReportHub(Shoals)\Sales\Daily 
Reports\F&I Daily Reports\CIT Report.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Activate
objWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh everything
objWorkbook.DoEvents 'Let Excel finish
WScript.Sleep 20000
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
DoEvents
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I need the code to open the workbook (while my PC is locked and unattended), refresh all data within the workbook, save it and close the workbook.

Comment: Remove both `DoEvents` and `sleep` as they are unnecessary..

Comment: Excel completes each of your commands before doing the next. `DoEvents` is dangerous and should never be used to randomly solve a problem. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176056/python-equivalent-of-vb6-doevents/54191214#54191214

Comment: Thank you. I have read the post you shared and I understand that DoEvents can cause issues by allowing things to run unchecked and the script never be able to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable = `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")` and then loop `Do Events` until `objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time") > variable`

```
Dim s

s = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Do Until objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time") > s
    DoEvents
Loop
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

**EDIT:**

Added to body of original code per OP's comment

```
Dim s
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\llfs01\ReportHub(Shoals)\Sales\Daily 
Reports\F&I Daily Reports\CIT Report.xlsm")

s = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Activate
objWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh everything

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Do Until objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time") > s
    DoEvents
Loop
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: I apologize in advance for having to ask this, but how would that look in relation to my code?

Comment: Thank you for your help! At first I got an error message about the objWorkbook.DoEvents, but when I commented that line out - it appears to work as expected (refreshes and saves and closes) but I did get an error message from Excel. I believe that it's because it's trying to close while it's still technically saving. Is it possible to add a few seconds to the time it should wait after saved?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to delete that out before I posted it, it's edited now. What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: It must have just been a fluke with Excel that caused the error and I have ran it many times since then and it's working properly. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Great, happy to have helped!